# Change color of default nav-bar without losing navigation controls

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

```
<ion-view view-title="Title">
  <ion-content>
  Content Here
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The above code gives me the default view of ionic I need to change the color of header keeping the default navigation controllers (like menu/back icon) instead of defining a new header bar as below.

```
<ion-view view-title="Title">
  <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>
 Content Here
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Is there a clean way to slove the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make any css class

```
.your-sample-class{
  background: #color-code !important
}
```

And add this class to nav bar of your project this way:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar your-sample-class" ></ion-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 5):

For the ionic 2 you can change you background color for navbar like that And you can add custom colors http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Connection Bluetooth</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click) = "startScanning()" ion-button>
                <!--<ion-icon name="refresh-circle"></ion-icon>-->
                <!--SCAN-->
                <ion-icon name='refresh'  md="md-refresh"></ion-icon>

            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#078ECD"/>
```

to the file config.xml for editing status bar panel's color

There is a plugin for it: [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

Also if you want to change color only for header, add these lines for your css/scss:

```
ion-header-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.bar.bar-positive {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or whatever
=)

Comment: this is not a good practice to override ionic classes like `.bar-positive`. Even if that is the case, it should be enclosed in some parent class, so it effects only that specific page. Otherwise this will effect whole application where `.bar-positive` is used.

Comment: I agree with you, but I wrote ".bar.bar-positive", not just ".bar-positive" like you said - of course they are different.
And it works well in my projects.
I prefer to use less classes, and your variant is also good.
I don't think that !important is necessary - just try to use it less.

Comment: For my current fix which is very small so for this fix I just go with @mudasserajaz and yeah! using `!important` is not a best solution in the long run. I feel we can just override default to our own colors will save a lot of time. Thankx guys :)

Comment: You're welcome, anyway =)
There are a lot of solutions, just choose the best for you